# Rails Watir Webdriver - select option not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, web-scraping, watir-webdriver

I'm writing a web scraper in Rails and can't get Watir to select an option from a select tag. I've tried multiple variations but by all accounts this should work:

```
browser.select_list(:id, "system").select("PC")
```

I've tested to make sure both the select box and value are present, I've used sleep to delay the click to allow everything to load, I've used `.when_present`, I've tried it in pry (I can set and unset checkboxes in pry and see the effect live, not the case with the select box) and I'm out of ideas. There's no error messages, it just doesn't do anything.

Here's the full code:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'pry'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'http://www.co-optimus.com/games.php'

browser.div(id: "system-modal").link(class: "close-reveal-modal").click

sleep 5
browser.select_list(:id, "system").when_present.select("PC")

sleep 1
browser.checkbox(id: "couch").when_present.set

sleep 2
browser.link(text: "Find Games").when_present.click
```

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? Your code worked as expected for me while using Firefox v50.1.0 with Geckodriver v0.11.1 (win32).

Comment: I was using an earlier version because of a restriction with another project. titusfortner's solution worked for me though

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? Is there something wrong with the way I asked it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, watir-webdriver has been deprecated by watir. If you use use `gem "watir", "~> 6.0.0"` you do not need to include `#when_present` (or the sleeps).

This works for me (it uses Chrome by default now)

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'http://www.co-optimus.com/games.php'
browser.div(id: "system-modal").a.click
browser.select_list(id: "system").select("PC")
browser.checkbox(id: "couch").set
browser.button(text: "Find Games").click
```

Using `browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox` on my screen is actually giving issues clicking "Find Games" (I'd need to do a workaround with [watir-scroll](https://github.com/p0deje/watir-scroll) to get past the javascript overlaying), but works with the select list just fine. (This is also with Firefox 50).

There were some issues with Select Lists using earlier versions of Firefox with geckodriver, so you might need to use Chrome or update your Firefox version.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I must have been reading from an old tutorial

Comment: The latest docs we have, and where new stuff will get added: http://watir.github.io/ Also feel free to converse with us on The Watir channel in the Selenium Slack if you want: https://seleniumhq.herokuapp.com/